# ArcGIS 10.1, Python 2.7 "RuntimeError: A column was specified that does not exist. "

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, cursor

When this error is returned, a problematic column must have been encountered.

I would like to know WHICH non-existent column has been "specified".

How do I obtain this apparently obvious piece of information? Is there a good reason why it  is not supplied by default?

The code included a searchCursor that iterates through a list of variables. I guess I could comment all these out and one by one bring them back in till I find the culprit.

Comment: I can make some suggestions about ways to inspect the fields in a feature class, but I don't know if that's really what you want. As far as I know, there is no log of _which_ field name you asked for that it couldn't provide.

Comment: I think you will need to isolate the line of Python code that led to this error first. The full error message should provide a line number that you can use to look up the line of code that led to it.

Comment: Hi PolyGeo and Erica and thank you for your responses. The code included a searchCursor that iterates through a list of variables. I guess I could comment all these out and one by one bring them back in till I find the culprit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

prior to running the search cursor, you could do something like

```
flds=[]
fldObj=arcpy.ListFields(yourfeatureclass)
for fld in fldObj:
    flds.append(fld.name)

#then loop through your list of variables that the search cursor is looking for:
missingvar=[]
for v in variables:
    if v not in flds:
        missingvar.append(v)

#and print the missing variables
for m in missingvar:
    print m,'\n'
```

Comment: Already found one bug with your script. :-) But it outputs an unordered list (dictionary? - yet you haven't used {}) of the variables until it falls over. I was expecting to see the variables in the order in which they were created, but they seem to be in a random order. Is that what you expected? They appear like this: CE_UR_MEAN : {'INDEX': 7, 'TYPE': 'MEAN'}
_RECORDCOUNT : {'INDEX': 12, 'TYPE': 'COUNT'}. The next one appears simply as CE_UR, with no colon and nothing beyond. I presume this is the one that fails?

Comment: sorry for the bug. no, not was i would expect at all, though i didn't have an opportunity to test it. more information might be warranted, such as a sample of the variable list of fields that the search cursor is calling, and the maybe even the type of feature class (in a gdb?).

Comment: Thanks for coming back. All the field names are parameterised earlier in the script:  I will post the script in parts.

Comment: Sorry fluidmotion, I meant that using your script, I had found a bug in mine! Although I'm not out of the woods yet, you were a great help. Kudos.